# Which do you feel natural "question queue", "questions queue" or "queue of questions"?

Tags: nouns, singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

I'm writing programs in Swift language.
Which do you feel natural "question queue", "questions queue" or "queue of questions"?

Comment: All are valid...but it depends whether you have one question or more. But to stay clear, if coding permits, go for - *queue of questions*

Comment: Thanks! It seems good. I'll write it in Swift code as _queueOfQuestions_ .

Comment: I don't know Swift, so I don't know if it has its own conventions about naming variables, but in other programming languages I'd name the variable either `questionQueue` or `questions`. Similarly, if it were a list rather than a queue I'd use `questionList` or just `questions`.

Comment: Oh, `questions` is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your programming is pointing to a queue.

In that case, I would use "question queue".
Because you are describing a queue. What kind of queue? A "question queue".

If there are other queues, then you can follow the same format with them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm describing a queue, a question queue. Simple.

Comment: Agreed.  This is a good example of a *noun adjunct*, in which a noun ("question", here) modifies another noun ("queue") as though it were an adjective.